# How to use JPA CMT with glassfish 3.1

Tags: jpa, glassfish

I am new to JPA and want to try out simple examples on glassfish 3.1. I am able to run some sample programs with Bean Managed transactions. 
However when I am trying sames examples with CMT, I am getting transaction required exception.

Unable to get clue where I am going wrong.

My project is simple web project and I included JPA facet for entity generation.

May be a reason as I am not using EJB project so unable to get features of EJB container of glassfish app server....not sure about this...

my persitence.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="JPAPractise" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/JPAConnPool</jta-data-source>
    <class>model.Address</class>
    <class>model.Employee</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

normal servlet as trigger point:

```
@WebServlet("/TestJPA")
public class TestJPA extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;
/*@Resource 
UserTransaction tx;*/


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setEmployeeID("290874");
    e1.setName("Shashi Shankar");
    e1.setSalary(60000);
    try{
        //tx.begin();
        em.persist(e1);
        em.flush();
        //tx.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Please help me to know the real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With BMT, you are responsible for managing transactions, while in CMT it's the container's. Therefore your example is working with BMT.

`TestJPA` is a servlet & not an enterprise bean where the container will manage transactions.

**From documentation :**

> In an enterprise bean with container-managed transaction demarcation,
>   the EJB container sets the boundaries of the transactions. You can use
>   container-managed transactions with any type of enterprise bean:
>   session, or message-driven. Container-managed transactions simplify
>   development because the enterprise bean code does not explicitly mark
>   the transaction’s boundaries. The code does not include statements
>   that begin and end the transaction.

You can try something like below code.

```
try{
    em.getTransaction().begin();` 
    em.persist(e1);
    em.getTransaction().commit();`.
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    em.close();
}
```

Also, have to change persistence.xml to have `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transaction.

```
<persistence-unit name="JPAPractise" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/JPAConnPool</non-jta-data-source>
```